# Why I can not import utils in my Jupyter Notebook (Python 3.6) although it is installed?

Tags: python-3.x, module, installation, python-import

I have installed the package utils using conda but when I try to import it in my Jupyter Notebook I get an exception:

```
import utils
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-32411ba4e9a6> in <module>()
----> 1 import utils

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

If I try installing again using pip this time I get the expected message:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alienware\Documents>pip install python-utils
Requirement already satisfied: python-utils in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-utils) (1.10.0)
```

Other modules are imported without any problem (e.g. featuretools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed `python-utils` but are importing `utils`. These are two different packages. If you want to use the `utils` package, install it with `pip install utils`. Otherwise, use `import python_utils` if you want to use that package.