# Unable to import Utils and Generators package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, importerror

I already referred these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064348/no-module-named-utils-error-on-compiling-py-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767676/why-do-i-keep-getting-this-no-module-named-utils-error), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704653/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-utils), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545142/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-utils), [5](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4864)

but am still unable to fix this issue. Might be because the other issues are too technical.

I did the below

a) I launched the jupyter notebook (save the file in Desktop)

b) Imported regular packages like Pandas, Numpy, Scipy etc.

c) Later I tried importing `Utils` and `Generators` package but it threw error.

```
pip install Utils  #success
pip install Generators #success
pip list-v #returned the below location

utils 1.0.1     c:\users\test\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages pip
generators 2020.4.27 c:\users\test\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages pip

When I tried importing `Utils` and `Generators` package, I get the same error as well

import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Utils
import Generators

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utils'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Generators'
```

Does importing `Utils` package require any other file?

Why is that people often talk about project directory for importing utils successfully? I am just trying to import it like `Pandas` which doesn;t care about project directory. I just launched a jupyter notebook and trying to install `Utils` package

How can I import these packages successsfully? can't these packages be imported like regular packages such as `pandas`? Because I installed all those packages brand new and they all are imported successfully

I also tried the suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720818/why-i-can-not-import-utils-in-my-jupyter-notebook-python-3-6-although-it-is-in) by typing `import python_utils` but doesn't help

Any tutorial or steps on how can this be resolved would really be helpful for me to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements are **case sensitive** while the `pip` is **case insensitive**.

According to [`PEP-0426`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) which describes a mechanism for publishing and exchanging metadata related to Python distributions/packages,

> All comparisons of distribution names MUST be case insensitive, and
> MUST consider hyphens and underscores to be equivalent.

So technically `pip install Utils`, `pip install UTILS` or `pip install utils` will all install the same distribution/package named `utils`.

To fix the problem you have to change your code from

```
import Utils
import Generators
```

to

```
import utils
import generators
```

Comment: @TheGreat Sure :)